# Can we bind binder service through broadcast receiver?

Tags: android, broadcastreceiver, bindservice

I want to start binder service once application receive broadcast, So can i bind service from receiver like startService or do i need to send callback to activity to bind service? As per my knowledge broadcast receiver has time limit of 10 sec, so does that time limit would affect if i bind service from receiver?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`BroadcastReceiver` cannot bind to a service. More specifically, the `context` provided in `onReceive()` cannot be used to bind to a service or to register dynamic `BroadcastReceiver`s. You will need to start an `Activity` or `Service` of your own.

Comment: Thanks Karakuri :)